# Real method execution instead of mocks

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito, apache-httpclient-4.x

Hello I have the following test that mocks Http calls to a remote server , but the mocks are disregarded and the real network stuff gets executed
what am I missing?

```
public class MyTest {

    static ActorSystem system;
    JavaTestKit senderProbe;
    JavaTestKit jobRunnerProbe;
    TestActorRef<RoutesManager> underTest;
    static Service webapp3;
    static JSONObject job;
    static JSONArray portsArray;
    static JSONArray routesArray;
    static JSONObject routeObject;
    private static final RoutesManager routeManager = mock(RoutesManager.class);
    private static final HttpClient  client = mock(DefaultHttpClient.class);
    private static final HttpGet  get = mock(HttpGet.class);
    private static final HttpResponse response = mock(CloseableHttpResponse.class);
    private static final HttpEntity entity = mock(HttpEntity.class);
    private static final InputStream inputStream  = mock(InputStream.class);


    @BeforeClass
    public static void setup() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, JSONException {

        system = ActorSystem.create();
    }


    @AfterClass
    public static void teardown() {
        JavaTestKit.shutdownActorSystem(system);
        system = null;
    }



    @Before
    public void makeActorUnderTest() throws ClientProtocolException, ParseException, IOException, JSONException {
        senderProbe = new JavaTestKit(system);
        jobRunnerProbe = new JavaTestKit(system);
        String token = JobRunner.getAuthToken(TestResources.AUTH_ENDPOINT, TestResources.APCERA_USER, TestResources.APCERA_PASSWORD);
        underTest = new TestActorRef<RoutesManager>(system,
                Props.create(RoutesManager.class,
                        token, webapp3, apcSession),
                senderProbe.getRef(), UUID.randomUUID().toString());

        HttpGet getRoute = new HttpGet("actual Api");
        Header header = // set header
        JSONObject routesJson  = new JSONObject();
        List<String> jobids = new ArrayList<String>();
        jobids.add("jobuuid");
        routesJson.put(webapp3.getRoute(), jobids);
        Mockito.when(routeManager.buildHttpClient(token)).thenReturn(client);
        Mockito.when(routeManager.buildHttpGet(webapp3)).thenReturn(getRoute);

        Mockito.when(client.execute(getRoute)).thenReturn(response);
        Mockito.when(response.getEntity()).thenReturn(entity);
        Mockito.when(entity.getContent()).thenReturn(inputStream);
        Mockito.when(entity.getContent().toString()).thenReturn(routesJson.toString());
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);


    }

    @Test

    public void myTest() throws ClientProtocolException, ParseException, IOException, JSONException {
        underTest.tell(new \triggeringMsg,underTest.underlyingActor().token), senderProbe.getRef());
        senderProbe.watch(underTest);
        senderProbe.expectTerminated(Duration.create(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS),
                underTest); 

    }

}
```

And the source code

```
    //Find all jobs that share a common route between them
        if (msg instanceof triggering message) {
            HttpClient client = buildHttpClient(message.token);
            HttpGet get = buildHttpGet(message.service);

            HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
            String json_string_response = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            if (!json_string_response.isEmpty()) {
                delegate(new JSONObject(json_string_response), message.service, message.token);
                getSelf().tell(PoisonPill.getInstance(), getSelf());

            }

        }

else {
//unhandled
}
```

And the stack trace

```
JSONObject["value set in the set up of test"] not found.
org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["] not found.
```

Comment: I don't see where you actually **use** your mocks?

Comment: sorry, just updated the question

Comment: Hints: A) you want us to spend our time to help you, so please spend the 1 minute it takes to properly format/indent all of your code B) err, what exactly is your question ... sorry, but your questions reads/looks like written by a person asking the very first question here.

Comment: updated the question

Comment: And another hint: please learn a bit about **static**. It seems that you think that everything should be static. To the contrary: using static is the absolute exception!

Answer (score 1):

first you need to refactor the code in such a way it can inject the `HttpClient` for mocking.

```
protected HttpClient buildHttpClient() {
    return HttpClients.custom()./* other config */.build();
}
```

and change

```
HttpClient client = HttpClients.custom().setDefaultHeaders(headers).build();
```

to

`HttpClient client = buildHttpClient();`

In your test,

```
when(underTest.buildHttpClient()).thenReturn(mockClient);
```

EDIT:

`MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(UnderTest);`

or

```
@Spy  UnderTest underTestClass = new UnderTest();
```

Comment: Hi, changing to that gives a org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 

when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
For example:
    when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);

Also, this error might show up because:
1. you stub either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
   Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
2. inside when() you don't call method on mock but on some other object.
3. the parent of the mocked class is not public.
   It is a limitation of the mock engine.

Comment: although, I did change it to underTest.underLyingactor

Comment: check edit, what is underLyingactor ? i assume the real method call is happening  client.execute(get); ?? is it still right?

Comment: yes, but underTest here is just an TestactorRef so to access the method I have to access it as underTest.underlyingActor.method

Comment: I mocked the underlying actor which got rid of the above error but the mocks are still arent used

Comment: can you add the updated test code, source code and stacktrace to see method calls.

Comment: i've updatd thequestion

Comment: is it the full stack trace?couldn't see any line numbers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134922/discussion-between-user-mda-and-sasi-kathimanda).